# MongoDB online migration to CosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to make online data migration with help of the Azure Database Migration Service from Mongo3.4 to Azure Cosmos DB. I deployed all settings for the online migration but I received a warning message:

"errorType":"ReplicationNotSupported", "warningDetail":"Replication has been requested but the source cluster does not support it. The migration will continue without replication."

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Is there a problem?  The message did say the migration would continue.

Comment: It's a problem to migrate a big amount of data for the prod env because we don't want to lose any data (migration will work like an offline migration)